# How to return all sequences of numbers that sum to a given positive integer given that integer?

Tags: php, algorithm

For example an input of 3 would return [1,1,1], [2,1], and [1,2]

I know a lot of combination/permutation problems involve a **recursive function that calls itself inside of a loop** but I'm unable to see an appropriate way to apply it to this problem.

It's a concept I'm trying to grasp, here's what I have so far...

```
function numberToAddends($number, $arr, $k){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        $arr[$k] = $i;
        numberToAddends($k-$i, $arr, $k + 1);
    }

    if($k <=0){
        print_r($arr);
    }
}
```

For test input, you can use something like numberToAddends(3, $arr, 0);

Am I thinking along the right path?  Can anyone provide complete php syntax to solve this problem along with commented code?

Comment: Shouldn't it give `[3]` as a solution as well?

Comment: *commented code*, some coffee, perhaps a nice doughnut to ?

Comment: No, all but the original number

Comment: @Dagon Sorry man, it's just really frustrating, I'm trying to understand this problem but I don't even know where to begin

Comment: Similar to Fibonacci, build the result from 1 to n instead of n to 1. By doing it that way you can reuse the results of any 1…n-1.

Comment: Closed as not a real question? But he's just asking about integer partitions, and Knuth has written most of volume 4A fascicule 3 about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an algorithm that solves this problem by reusing the sub-result from 1 to *n*:

```
$number = 3;
$addends = array();
for ($x=1; $x<=$number; $x++) {
    $addends[$x] = array();
    for ($y=$x-1; $y>0; $y--) {
        foreach ($addends[$y] as $z) {
            $addends[$x][] = array_merge($z, array($x-$y));
        }
    }
    $addends[$x][] = array($x);
}
var_dump($addends);
```

This builds the result set for *x* by combining any already known result *z* for any *y* < *x* with the difference of *x* and *y* and finally *x* itself.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is "integer partitions" of a number. Google should point you to lots of code, or look at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/11/partitions/) for an explanation and code.

The basic idea is a simple recursive process. There is a single partition of 0, the empty set (). There is a single partition of 1, the set (1). There are two partitions of 2, the sets (1 1) and (2). There are three partitions of 3, the sets (1 1 1), (1 2) and (3). There are five partitions of 4, the sets (1 1 1 1), (1 1 2), (1 3), (2 2), and (4). There are seven partitions of 5, the sets (1 1 1 1 1), (1 1 1 2), (1 2 2), (1 1 3), (1 4), (2 3) and (5). And so on. In each case, the next-larger set of partitions is determined by adding each integer x less than or equal to the desired integer n to all the sets formed by the partition of n − x, eliminating any duplicates.